# How are my tests not affecting the database...?

Tags: database, django, webtest

I recently switched from using regular old tests to using WebTest and this "No Database Test Runner"

```
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner

class NoTestDbDatabaseTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Here's an example test which HAS to be hitting the database somehow...

What is happening? Are my tests hitting the database but rolling back to some old state? Test-to-test I can see that each created listing has an incremented id.

```
    def test_image_upload(self):
        form_data = self.listing_form_defaults.copy()
        form_data['images-TOTAL_FORMS'] = '3'

        upload_files = [
            ('images-0-image', 'testdata/1.png'),
            ('images-1-image', 'testdata/2.png'),
            ('images-2-image', 'testdata/3.png'),
        ]

        form_resp = self.app.post(
            reverse('listing_create'),
            form_data,
            upload_files=upload_files,
            user='kmike'
        ).follow()

        assert len(form_resp.context['listing'].images.all()) == 3
```

`form_resp.context['listing'].images.all()` HAS to be hitting the database, I `print`'d it and it had database records from my database.

I'm just confused--my tests run blazing fast and don't seem to actually change my database, how is this working/happening?!

Comment: django is open source.  dive into the code, i'll bet it is pretty obvious.

Comment: What part of the code............?

Answer (score 0):

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.

See [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

Comment: No test database is created. My tests take about ~1 second, where they used to take 2 minutes+!